# Can I update other object's volatile variable directly?

Tags: java, volatile

Say I have an object looks like this.

```java
class Some {

    synchronized void some() {
        // do some with canceled
    }

    synchronized void setAsCanceled() {
        canceled = true;
    }

    volatile boolean canceled = false; // package-private
}
```

Now another object may update the `canceled`.

```java
class Other {

    void setSomeAsCanceled() {
        some.canceled = true; // Not calling the setAsCanceled()
    }

    private Some some = new Some();
}
```

Is it safe to update the `canceled` **volatile** variable directly? Or should I call the `setAsCanceled()` method?

Comment: short answer yes, since this assignment is an [atomic access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Comment: @Mr.Typo Thank you for the comment. Your short comment with a link deserves a whole answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable is created and used, it also exists in a cache. This cache isn't always in sync especially when you are using multiple threads.  When you mark a variable as `volatile`, you are telling the system that the cache has to be updated immediately so that anyone else using it will have the updated value.

I’m addition the keyword volatile is still valid in modern programming languages and is used to indicate that a variable may be modified by multiple threads or processes concurrently. This is especially important in programs that use shared memory or memory-mapped I/O.

When a variable is declared as volatile, the compiler and processor are instructed to treat it with a higher level of caution and to avoid certain optimizations that might interfere with the correct operation of the program. For example, the compiler might be prevented from caching the value of the variable in a register or from reordering instructions that access the variable.

One reason why the volatile keyword is still important today is that modern processors often use techniques such as out-of-order execution and speculative execution to improve performance. These techniques can cause the processor to execute instructions in a different order than the order in which they appear in the code, which can lead to unexpected behavior if the programmer is not careful. The volatile keyword can be used to prevent such optimizations from occurring on a particular variable, ensuring that the variable is accessed in a predictable way.

In summary, the volatile keyword is still relevant today because it allows programmers to control how variables are accessed and modified in multithreaded or concurrent programs, which is an important consideration when writing high-performance code that executes on modern processors.

Comment: Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent. No matter if you are using volatile or not.